# How put cells in UICollectionView one on another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have UICollectionView with customLayOut, when I start scrolling, 
I change x coordinate for the cell that should start to be visible - in order to be visible from the begining.

```
-(void)layoutSubviewsWithAttributes:(NSMutableArray *)theAttributes {
CGFloat halfScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2;
CGPoint startOfScreen = CGPointMake(self.timeLineCollection.bounds.origin.x, 25.f);
for(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in theAttributes) {
  if(CGRectContainsPoint(attribute.frame, startOfScreen)) {
     NSLog(@"Intersect %@", NSStringFromCGRect(attribute.frame));
    attribute.frame = CGRectMake(startOfScreen.x, startOfScreen.y, attribute.frame.size.width, attribute.frame.size.height);
}
```

}

but in some cases this cell appears on the top of the next one cell (wrong behaviour),

[image]

another time, that cell in under the next one cell (as I need it to be placed).

[image]

Could you advice, how to sort that cells to be placed hierarchically one on another (like cards).

Thank you in advance, for any help.

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel

Comment: @shallowThought , thank you, but I dont see solution for my issue there

Comment: @Melany how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @RajanSingh you can see my solution here in answers, it was very simple, just with zIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` has such a property as `zIndex`, that - Specifies the item’s position on the *z axis*.
So to tell cells to be set one after another, I just set to each attribute, `zIndex` - number of each cell and it places it one after another, inside the customLayOut.

```
for (NSInteger item = 0; item < self.cellCountPrograms; item++) {
    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:0];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes =
    [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    itemAttributes.frame = [self frameForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    itemAttributes.zIndex = item;
    cellProgramLayoutInfo[indexPath] = itemAttributes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with negative value it may help as i haven't tried but i am sure it should work like this.

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return -5.0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for an advice, but it didnt help, unfortunatly.